# Trigger mvvm command from eventcallback in blazor

Tags: mvvm, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm using the CommunityToolkit Mvvm for a Blazor wasm app.
I'm using a component that provides eventcallbacks. Previously in xamarin and WPF we had converters to go from an eventcallback to a command. I', looking to to do something similar with the communitytoolkit in blazor, but I can't find something similar. So how do I go from EventCallback to RelayCommand?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing:

In the razor view with an EventCallback of int named ValueChanged

```
ValueChanged="@((arg) => ViewModel.OptionChangedCommand.Execute(arg))"
```

In the ViewModel I created a RelayCommand manually, not with codegen.

The member:

```
public RelayCommand<int> OptionChangedCommand { get; }
```

in the constructor:

```
OptionChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<int>(OptionChanged);
```

handling:

```
private void OptionChanged(int obj)
{            
      ....
}
```